# Silverlight - Fill a Rectangle (or other controls which have a Brush Property) with a custom UserControl

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I need to fill a Rectangle with a custom UserControl. The rectangle's .Fill property accepts a Brush and in Silverlight there is no equivalent for VisualBrush.

I've found this post - http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/silverlight-visualbrush-and-rounded-corners/ - with a possible solution. However this approach requires the UserControl (which will be used to fill the rectangle) to be rendered first outside the rectangle so that the VisualImage can convert it to a WritableBitmapImage.

Does anyone know any alternate solution? I would prefer not having to render the user control outside the rectangle and remove it afterwards, because there is the possibility for some flickrs to occur.

Thanks and best regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternate solution if you must be using a rectangle and brush for its fill.

I take it you already have a reason not to simply use a `Border` containing the `UserControl` directly?  If you don't want the usercontrol to response to the mouse you could include in the `Border` a `Grid` containing both your `UserControl` and a `Rectangle` with a transparent fill.

Comment: I've used the Rectangle for the sake of explaining the problem. What I'm really using in my scenario is a Telerik's control (MapPolygon) which uses a Brush to Fill its content, so the problem is still the same! Thanks for help though!